# Forming a query string from multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, sql, checkbox

I'm trying to form a query string from multiple checkboxes that will be used to query my database.

I have the following form:

```
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">

            <input type="checkbox" name="wheat" id="checkbox-1a" class="custom" />
            <label for="checkbox-1a">Wheat Allergy</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="yeast" id="checkbox-2a" class="custom" />
            <label for="checkbox-2a">Yeast Allergy</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="sugar" id="checkbox-3a" class="custom" />
            <label for="checkbox-3a">Sugar Allergy</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="dairy" id="checkbox-4a" class="custom" />
            <label for="checkbox-4a">Dairy Allergy</label>
```

My PHP code is as follows:

```
        if(isset($_POST['wheat']))
        {
            $str1 = 'wheatfree = 1';
        }

        if(isset($_POST['yeast']))
        {
            $str2 = 'yeastfree = 1';
        }

        if(isset($_POST['sugar']))
        {
            $str3 = 'sugarfree = 1';
        }

        if(isset($_POST['dairy']))
        {
            $str4 = 'dairyfree = 1';
        }

        $fullsearch = $str1.$str2.$str3.$str4;

        $str_SQL = "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE ".$fullsearch;

        echo $str_SQL;
```

This is sort of doing what I require, but it's not very graceful.

For one, the sql query looks like this:

SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE sugarfree = 1dairyfree = 1

and if users choose not to select one I of course get an Undefined variable error for the str that hasn't been selected.

Not really sure how to fix this or where to go next. I'd like some logic in here that just amended the string based on what is checked on the form which then forms a nice clean SQL query I can run against my DB. But alas i'm lost :(

Help?

Comment: give the check boxes name="allergy[]" then you have a nice array, you can then use implode, to make the query string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
$options = array();
if(isset($_POST['wheat']))
{
    $options[] = 'wheatfree = 1';
}

if(isset($_POST['yeast']))
{
    $options[] = 'yeastfree = 1';
}

if(isset($_POST['sugar']))
{
    $options[] = 'sugarfree = 1';
}

if(isset($_POST['dairy']))
{
    $options[] = 'dairyfree = 1';
}

$fullsearch = implode(' AND ', $options);

$str_SQL = "SELECT * FROM recipes";
if ($fullsearch <> '') {
    $str_SQL .= " WHERE " . $fullsearch;
}

echo $str_SQL;
```

Comment: Heh, was just editing it to do that and change str to options when you commented. Thanks, though, and well spotted. _(This was in response to another comment, since deleted.)_

Comment: Ew, do you REALLY need all of these braces?

Comment: I love braces, me. Also, I find it's better to always add them - you never know when someone else will modify your code later and not spot an if with no braces ...

Comment: Thanks Dave, does exactly what I needed. Didn't think of throwing it into an array... :)

Comment: @Dave: Please see my answer which shows that there is no need for this verbose and redundant stream of conditionals.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Braces are one thing, conditionals another ;)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Fewer characters does not always make for better code. Using an array, as per your answer, is definitely an improvement ... ditching the braces isn't. In my opinion, at least.

Comment: @DaveChild: You're entitled to your opinion regarding braces, even though I heartily disagree with it. _Especially_ since you drop them onto the next line... what a waste of space, making things less legible! Note that I never claimed that fewer characters always makes for better code: you're right, it's not always true.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: The braces on the next line was from the original code from redcow. I usually keep the starting brace on the same line as the condition in my own code ...

Comment: @DaveChild: There's hope for you yet ;)

Answer (score 3):

Further to Dave's answer:

```
$options = Array();
$ingredients = Array('wheat', 'yeast', 'sugar', 'dairy');

foreach ($ingredients as $i)
   if (isset($_POST[$i]))
      $options[] = $i . 'free = 1';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM recipes";
if (count($options))
   $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $options);

echo $sql;
```

---

But why aren't you using the `value` property of checkboxes?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ingredients[]" value="wheat" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ingredients[]" value="sugar" />
```

etc.

Then:

```
$options = Array();
foreach ($_POST['ingredients'] as $i)
   $options[] = $i . 'free = 1'; // don't forget to escape $i somehow!

$sql = "SELECT * FROM recipes";
if (count($options))
   $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $options);

echo $sql;
```

Comment: Brilliant, didn't think of throwing it into an array *rollseyes* Thanks!

Comment: @redcow: I have expanded my answer to include a better alternative.

Comment: This is not necessarily better as it is prone to SQL injections now (I see you mentioned to escape `$i`). Personally I think a "whitelist" is better. But anyway, just my opinion. It is still an improvement compared to the original ;) (and you already got +1 form me ;))

Comment: @Felix: Yea, I wasn't really sure _tbh_. It's certainly a toss-up between extensibility and sanity. :)